# Wireless network cannot be connected until the adaptor is disabled and re-enabled

Tags: wireless-networking, mikrotik-routeros

My home Wi-Fi network powered by MikroTik RB951G-2HnD has issues with connectivity of some devices:

- Company laptop with Windows 10 is unable to reconnect to the hidden network until I disable and re-enable its wireless adapter. (Once I do that, it reconnects immediately.)
- Two older smartphones, both of the same model, always fail to connect. Some time ago, they were able to connect normally.

This leads me to suspection whether I could have changed something on the router what can create issues for Wi-Fi adaptors of these devices. (The router has typical setting 2.4 GHz, WPA2 + AES, one hidden primary network and one visible guest network.) But over the time, it is possible that I changed some of minor settings scattered through the many areas of configuration of the router. Is there area of settings possibly related to the above problems which should I inspect?

I attempted to set up logging on the router, but logs did not show any connection attempts incoming from these devices when they were failing. (Maybe I used improper logging category?)

Comment: Does it start working if you stop _(uselessly)_ hiding the network?

Comment: @grawity – the problem is present only when the network is hidden. If you know why hiding a network can cause these problems under some conditions, please add an answer.